# Problems with refreshing a form

Tags: c#

I have a form with labels A, B and C. In *static void Main()*, I say:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Application.Run(form1);
```

Form1 constructor calls

```
InitializeComponent();
updateForm();
```

where updateForm reads a log ((FtpWebRequest)WebRequest) from a remote machine and updates the labels appropriately.

I would like to constantly update the form, because the remote log file is changing every few minutes.

I tried calling form1.updateLog() in while(true) loop in the main method, but the form doesn't refresh. Also, form1.Refresh() doesn't seem to work.

Any hints?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing that in a loop then most likely on the UI thread. This means that you constantly tell the Form to repaint yet don't give it time or an opportunity to do so (remember: you're blocking the thread on which it would do that).

Instead use a timer and refresh from there, e.g. every 100 ms or so.

Comment: +1 For the timer idea. Use a timer and just update the text property of the labels, don't reload the whole form

Comment: Thanks for input. I'm confused, though. I should call form1.Refresh() using the timer in my main method?

Comment: I guess you have much larger problems than the form refresh issue, e.g. fundamental knowledge about how a Windows Forms application roughly works.